# Using excel 2013 extract the country extension from a large series urls

Tags: excel

I have a large list of urls that i need to break down by a variety of factors. One factor is if it is for a country other than the US. I have complied a list of all the extensions I'm searching for within the workbook (i.e., .az,.mx,.nl, etc.).
Due to the variety in the urls, simple extraction of TLD won't work on all. For example:

```
b2  http://www.domainname.in
b3  http://www.domainname.co.in
b4  http://www.domainname.in/un.htm
b5  https://www.domainname.in/wp.content/_input_3_.txt I
```

I was using `RIGHT(b2,LEN(b2)-FIND("*",SUBSTITUTE(b2,".","*",LEN(b2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(b2,".",""))))))` to extract the TLD for those in the b2 example. However, it will not work for those with other endings. I was considering searching for the third "/" in example b4, however longer urls (like b5) prevent that.
Is there a way to identify if there is a country extension present? Furthermore, would be be possible to have the column next to it list what the country extension is, if one exists. 
I currently have no working knowledge of Macros or VBA,

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is gonna be crazy.  So we know that the country code is attached to the domain name, and is usually the last two letters.  The first thing I would do is separate out the domain name. The formula would look something like this:

(I put all the URL's in column A so you'd have to fix the column reference)

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"//","/"),"/",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:B)*999-998,999))
```

What this does is replace the double `//` with a single `/` it then uses it as a delimiter and get's the second column which is the domain name.

Next we need to find the country code of the domain which you've already done but I'll use a slightly different formula.  If you had just the domain name in column A by itself you could extract it like this.

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE($A1,".",REPT(" ",LEN($A1))),LEN($A1)))
```

Now that we have those two formulas we can replace the `$A1` reference of the second formula with the first formula so that we aren't using a bunch of cells to extract the code.  The combined formula would look like this:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"//","/"),"/",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:B)*999-998,999)),".",REPT(" ",LEN(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"//","/"),"/",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:B)*999-998,999))))),LEN(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"//","/"),"/",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:B)*999-998,999)))))
```

Hope that helps